# Shallow copy in c#

Tags: c#

I understand the definition of shallow copy

Shallow copying is creating a new object and then copying the non-static fields of the current object to the new object. If a field is a value type --> a bit-by-bit copy of the field is performed; for a reference type --> the reference is copied but the referred object is not; therefore the original object and its clone refer to the same object.

but why static fields are not copied?

Answer (score 9):

Because static fields are not part of the object. You could access them with `ClassName.StaticValue`. In fact, you CAN'T access them with `ClassInstanceName.StaticValue`.

Answer (score 1):

Static fields are shared by all the instances of a particular class.

Answer (score 1):

Because static members are `class` level members not instance level which mean that static members common for all instances of given type.